# Laravel Blade adding double quotes around HTML attributes

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, helper

I'm writing a custom Laravel Helper that generates the img HTML tag dynamically (I use this to generate the img srcset and size attributes, because I use a CDN).
But when returning the generated string, double quotes are added around the attributes.
Spaces in attribute values are also broken into smaller attributes.

```
<img src="&quot;https://ik.imagekit.io/sdqrv2ex9bq/Rosa_de_Saron/cremacao_slide.jpg?ik-sdk-version=php-2.0.0&quot;srcset=&quot;https://ik.imagekit.io/sdqrv2ex9bq/Rosa_de_Saron/tr:w-768:/cremacao_slide.jpg?ik-sdk-version=php-2.0.0" 768\w,https:="" ik.imagekit.io="" sdqrv2ex9bq="" rosa_de_saron="" tr:w-1366:="" cremacao_slide.jpg?ik-sdk-version="php-2.0.0" 1366\w&quot;="" alt="Pessoa com urna funerária" width="1366" height="768">
```

This is my Helper:

```
function image_cdn($path, $sizes=[], $transform=[]){
        //CRIA OBJETO DO SDK
        $image = new ImageKit(
            env('IMAGEKIT_PUB_KEY'),
            env('IMAGEKIT_PRIV_KEY'),
            env('IMAGEKIT_ENDPOINT')
        );
        //ADICIONA URL DEFAULT
        $tagImg = ' src="'.$image->url([
            'path'=>$path,
            'transformation'=>$transform
        ]).'"';
        //ORDENA OS INTENS DO ARRAY
        $sizes = Arr::sort($sizes);
        //LOOP PARA GERAR CADA SIZE ENVIADO (SE HOUVER)
        foreach($sizes as $size){
            //GERA URL DA IMAGEM COM A TRANSFORMAÇÃO DO WIDTH
            $imageSet[] = $image->url([
                'path'=>$path,
                'transformation'=>[
                    ['width'=>$size],
                    $transform
                ]
            ])." $size\w";
            //GERA O ATRIBUTO SIZES
            $imageSize[] = "(max-width: $size\px) $size\px";
        }
        //SE FORAM SIZES PARA A IMAGEM ADICIONA ELES NA TAG GERADA
        $tagImg .= isset($imageSet) ? 'srcset="'.implode(',',$imageSet).'"' : '';
        //RETORNO
        return $tagImg;
    }
```

The Helper call:

```
<img {{ image_cdn('cremacao_slide.jpg',[768,1366]) }} alt="Pessoa com urna funerária" width="1366" height="768">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is returning a fully built attribute that you want to display as-is. The `{{ }}` blade syntax, however, will escape your special characters.

You need to use the `{!! !!}` syntax to print your value without blade escaping it.

```
<img {!! image_cdn('cremacao_slide.jpg',[768,1366]) !!} alt="Pessoa com urna funerária" width="1366" height="768">
```

---

On a complete side note, I see your function is using the `env()` function directly. The `env()` function should only be used inside the config files, and the config values should be accessed inside your function. As it is written right now, this code will break if you ever cache your config (ex: in production).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I didn't see your reply and I didn't get any notification about it.
Reading the Laravel docs, I find the components and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

The other option, if you want to keep using the `{{ }}` escaped echo syntax, is to put your string into an `HtmlString` object. The `e` helper method, which escapes the strings for the echos, checks if what is being passed is `Htmlable` and will directly return the call to `toHtml` on it instead of escaping the content:

```
function returningSomeHtml(...)
{
    return new Illuminate\Support\HtmlString(...the HTML Content...);
}


{{ returningSomeHtml(...) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I didn't see your reply and I didn't get any notification about it.
Reading the Laravel docs, I find the components and it works for me.

Comment: @lagbox Nice. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using Blade Components, so it's working fine now.
Since the attribute value is added directly to the attribute's double quotes, the problem does not occur.

```
<img src="{{$imageDefault}}" {{$slot}}
@if ($imageSet)
    srcset="{{$imageSet}}"
    sizes="{{$imageSizes}}"
@endif
```

> 

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).